# JSON Delete not happning on button click

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
[LogInFilter]
    public JsonResult MemberDelete(Int32 MemID)
    {
        MemberTbl Mem = db.MemberTbls.Where(x => x.ID == MemID).FirstOrDefault();
        db.MemberTbls.Remove(Mem);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my HTML and Javascript:-

```js
 function DeleteMember(M_ID) {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure Delete Selected Member Record No.? " + M_ID)) {
            var data = { 'ID': M_ID }
            $.post('/Admin/MemberDelete', data,
            function (data) {
                if (data == true)
                    alert("Deleted Successfully!!");
                else
                    alert("Can't Delete. Contact Support Team.");
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
 format: @<text>
            @Html.Raw("<img src='/images/edit.png' title='Edit' onclick='EditMember(" + item.ID + ")' />")
            @Html.Raw("<img src='/images/delete.png' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteMember(" + item.ID + ")' />")
        </text>
```

On click of DeleteMember I'm getting the Message 
'Are You Sure Delete Selected Member Record No.? " + M_ID' 
and on OK click there's an error as:-
POST http://localhost:52422/Admin/MemberDelete 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Because you have not sent a value for parameter `MemID` and an exception is thrown. Change the method parameter to `int id`, or change the script to use `var data = { MemID: M_ID }` - they need to match

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot.